# Error accessing remote module registry in Terraform

Tags: terraform

We have been given a remote Terraform Private registry to utilise. Along with that came a credentials name and token.

Once we configured the general details on the terraform script, we created a .terraformrc file in the same dir (mac) and created the following

credentials "my remote registy"
token = "tokenvaluegoeshere"

When we run a terraform init we get the following error (for all modules)

> Error: Error Accessing remote module registry
> failed to retrieve available versions for module "x" from external.location - failed to request discovery document: 401 Unauthorised

It feels like i haven't got something correctly setup in terraform (even though it looks fine)
I have tried running terraform from different locations on my mac also created new .terraformrc files but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

if you are running a code from VScode - enter terraform login in VScode , once you login it will be routed to terraform.io page and copy the token and paste in the value, then you will be able to run the code.

Answer (score 0):

The `.terraformrc` file needs to be at your user's home.

Also, looks like the syntax for the file is the following

```
credentials "app.terraform.io" {
  token = "xxxxxx.atlasv1.zzzzzzzzzzzzz"
}
```

Source [here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/config/config-file)